# How to add a custom field to my page header

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Is there a way to add a custom field to change the image displayed in my web site's header?
I want the same imageto be displayed in every page, so I dont know how to make a general custom field instead of a field specific for each page.

```
<?php
  $img = the_field('background_url'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way after reading ACF documentation, in order to make the custom field's scope global, I have to add the post/page ID on it:

```
$video_file = get_field('background_video',156);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add Options page for ACF with the help of below code:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    acf_add_options_page();
}
```

and then assign options to acf field.
now you can access this common field with `<?php the_field('logo', 'option'); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ACF Pro then you can create an option page and create Header, Footer fields into that. check the below link.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the header image is loaded from the `header.php` file in your theme?

If you want the same background image on all pages you could set the default header image via the `set_theme_mod` function. The `set_theme_mod` is responsible for all modification values for the current theme. In this case you would want to set the `header_image` property.

*Start with setting the default `header_image` for your theme in your themes `functions.php` file:*

```
 function theme_setup() {
     set_theme_mod(‘header_image’, ‘http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/yourimage.png’);
 }
 add_action('after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup');
```

*Display the newly set header image in your theme file responsible for displaying your header (assumingly `header.php`):*

```
 <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <div id="site-header">
        <img alt="" src="<?php header_image(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to be able to upload custom images from within the Customizer (Appearance > Header) in the wp admin section you could use the `custom_header` property, you'll find more information about it here:

[Theme Handbook: Custom Headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/)

Answer (score 0):

Please install [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin and you would easily get the image. While creating an image field there would be an option which name is Return Format, please select any of them and you would get results accordingly.

- Image Array
- Image URL
- Image ID

For further please follow ACF official documentation.
[AdvancedCustomField](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Comment: I already hame ACF, my problem is about how to make it work in a general scope and not in only one kind of page.

Comment: If you're using common header.php file for each of wp pages then you just need to call that field and image will appear on the header.

In header.php file you just need to get that field like as below:

<?php 
$getImage = get_field('header_image');
if($getImage):
?>
    <div id="site-header">
        <img alt="" src="<?php echo $getImage; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>